# How can i load a JSON configuration in runtime in a React app?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a React app (with static content, not using Node.js) and i need to load a configuration file (JSON).

The file loading needs to be in runtime, because the configuration needs to have different data, related with the server where the application is hosted.

Due this last requirement, i can't load the file using, for instance, webpack externals, because the application doesn't update the configurations when the the JSON file is updated.

What is the best way to do that?

I've done that using the Fetch API (http request to load the file), but maybe there's a better way to do that.

Comment: `fetch` is fine for that purpose.

Comment: @Renée But is the right way to do that? I mean, the right way to load settings in a React app is making a http call to get the file?

Comment: If possible, it might be better to inject the settings into a `<script>` tag on the server side and read that in your app. That way you can save an HTTP request and load a bit faster. In a 100% static app, that's not possible, though. For a 100% static app you'll need some form of HTTP request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have at least 2 options here depending on your use case:

1. Fetch the config like you mentioned. What I usually do in these
   scenarios is put a `data-attribute` on my root with the server url
   that will hold my config data (as in my case I don't know the domain
   of the server at compile time).

i.e: `<div id="root" data-url="yourDomain.com/app"></div>`.

Grab this value and pass it
    as prop in to the App.   `index.js` for example:

```
    const root = document.getElementById('root');
    const url = root.getAttribute('data-url');
    const configPromise = fetch(url);
    configPromise.then((res) => res.json())
      .then(config => render(<App config={config} />, root) );
```

2. Store the config data to a global object variable and use it inside
   your app.

I like the first option more even though it forces you to do an ajax request.

Comment: I went with a similar approach, but fetched a physical file from public.  This allowed my CI/CD solution to do config transforms on the file.

Comment: @MichielCornille What does it mean to "fetch a physical file from public"?

Comment: How do you make `App` have a `config`?